# SNS DwellTimeMs is high after being idle for some time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using AWS SNS -> SQS -> Lambda.

In some of the messages I send to SNS, it takes around 10 seconds of dwell time. This happens with the first message after I don't send any messages for few hours. Remaining requests have very short dwell time before it gets idle again.
Dwell time is the time between the publish timestamp and just before handing off to an Amazon SNS endpoint according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html#:%7E:text=Determining%20the%20message%20dwell%20time%20(the%20time%20between%20the%20publish%20timestamp%20and%20just%20before%20handing%20off%20to%20an%20Amazon%20SNS%20endpoint).)

I couldn't find anything in AWS documentation about this. I am assuming this time is for its internal processing to prepare the resources etc. But is there a way to set or optimize this?

Note that I don't use it to send SMS messages. Most of the documentation related to this issue is around SMS messages.

This is what I see in SNS Cloudwatch Logs:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "9ab621ce-2aa2-5c52-8af9-7cec93bb1d71",
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:MYSNSTOPICARNGOESHERE",
        "timestamp": "2021-10-27 02:18:01.46"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "deliveryId": "30e74859-5540-45z9-a12d-d4099c31af31",
        "destination": "arn:aws:sqs:MYSQSARNGOESHERE",
        "providerResponse": "{\"sqsMessageId\":\"8415002d-996e-40af-a613-df72x5dfaez7\",\"sqsRequestId\":\"1391a8e5-5376-5cfe-969d-f117ea55cz39\"}",
        "dwellTimeMs": 9854,
        "statusCode": 200
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Comment: Dwell time is for push notifications and SMS messages if I'm not mistaken - are you seeing Dwell time in the CloudWatch logs when sending normal messages? If so - please attach CloudWatch logs

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary, Yes I am seeing Dwell time in cloudwatch logs when sending normal messages. This SNS has 4 SQS subscribers that process the messages in Lambda. I updated the question with a sample SNS log entry.

Comment: I use HttpPost request to https://sns." + MYAWSRegion() + ".amazonaws.com.

Comment: Strange - your SQS queue takes 10 seconds to take the message? I thought it may be a Lambda cold start but it's between SNS and SQS - is your SQS queue in the same region as the SNS topic?

Comment: Yes. Everything is in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not much documentation around DwellTimeMS in AWS, we opened a case and found that it's a known defect with AWS SNS, which may take a few months to fix.